# Facebook Events Display Order

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-access-token

I made a page where you can see Event from a Public Page

The PHP Code

```
<?php
require 'src/facebook.php';
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId' => 'ID',
    'secret' => 'SECRET',
    'cookie' => true, 
));
try{
    $events=$facebook->api('/PAGE/events?access_token=TOKEN');
}catch (FacebookApiException $e){
    error_log($e);
}
foreach ($events["data"] as $event){
    // Time
    $startTime=strtotime($event["start_time"]);
        // Only Upcoming events
        if ((time()-$startTime)<=60*60*24*1 || $startTime>time()){

                echo '<li><a href="#" id="'.$event["id"].'" class="event_link">
                <img class="ui-li-thumb" src="https://graph.facebook.com/'.$event["id"].'/picture?type=small" width="70px;" height="100%" />
                <h3 class="ui-li-heading">'.$event['name'].'</h3>
                </a></li>';
            }
        }
?>
```

It is working Fine just I get the closest event last one in list

How can I change the order of output??(If it is possible ofcourse).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to use `fql` for that. [FQL - Event](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/event)

So that with in the query you could use, `ORDER BY`, to sort in the order wrt any parameter

For eg:

> select eid from event where creator=PAGE_ID and eid in (select eid from event_member where uid=PAGE_ID) ORDER BY start_time DESC

Comment: If possible can you give more info?

Comment: as in what? fql queries are just similar to graph api you are using

Answer (score 2):

You can use [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php):

```
//Sorts by name. Switch 'name' for other sorts.
//Switch 1 and -1 to reverse the sort.
usort($events["data"],function($a,$b){
    if ($a['name'] == $b['name']) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a['name'] < $b['name']) ? -1 : 1;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
require 'src/facebook.php';
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId' => 'ID',
    'secret' => 'SECRET',
    'cookie' => true, 
));
$fql = "SELECT 
            name, pic, start_time 
        FROM 
            event 
        WHERE 
            eid IN ( SELECT eid FROM event_member WHERE uid = PAGE_ID ) 
        AND 
            start_time >= now()
        ORDER BY 
            start_time asc";

$param  =   array(
    'method'    => 'fql.query',
    'query'     => $fql,
    'callback'  => ''
);

$fqlResult   =   $facebook->api($param);
foreach( $fqlResult as $keys => $values ){

    echo '<li><a href="#" id="'.$values["id"].'" class="event_link">
                <img class="ui-li-thumb" src="'.$values['pic'].'" width="70px;" height="100%" />
                <h3 class="ui-li-heading">'.$values['name'].'</h3>
                </a></li>';

}
?>
```

SOLVED!